# <class 'pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties'> to Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, arima

```
d = {'date': [2020-01-01, 2020-01-02], 'items_sold': [30, 40]}
train = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA  
model=ARIMA(train,order=(1,1,1),freq='d')  
results=model.fit()
e = {'date': [2020-01-03], 'items_sold': [25]}`  
test = pd.DataFrame(data=e)  
X_test = test.date
test['forecasted'] = results.predict(X_test)
```

OR

```
test['forecasted'] = results.predict(X_test.dt)
```

I'm currently trying to pass a test dataset consisting of dates into my ARIMA fitted model, but i keep getting this error:

```
Cannot convert input [<pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties object at 0x000001D04836E8C8>] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties'> to Timestamp
```

I have tried using my original dataset which consists of date inputs (eg. 2020-10-16), as well as converting my test dataset into datetime by using .dt but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Oh no, what did you do to get that horrible error???

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, there isn't enough detail here to give any real answer. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including sample input data and a minimal amount of code that will replicate the error

Comment: thanks for the tip! i've added a small bit of the code in (am also having problems with line break in the code in the question -- double space doesnt start a new line? but thats not the main problem hahaha ugh)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of offering thanks, apologies etc which only [add noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) and should be avoided as completely irrelevant, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you this time). This will be a real courtesy to readers and possible respondents.